# How can I copy the URLs of the tabs I have open in firefox?

Tags: url, firefox, tabs, copy, paste

Just wanted a way to copy the URLs of some of the tabs I had open in Firefox to paste into a document.

Comment: In the future, similar questions should be asked on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a work-around...
*without scripts or addons*

1. Select tabs
   *CLICK a tab; then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+CLICK the end-one, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+CLICK each*
2. Right-click a tab
3. Select "Bookmark Tabs..." and save to "Other Bookmarks" or wherever
4. Show the Bookmarks bar
   *Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks*
5. Find and select all the bookmarks you just added
6. Copy
   *<kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; or Edit > Copy*
7. Paste :)

*Worked for me in Firefox 73, 2020 February 21*

I also liked that I could drag the selected tabs slightly and they moved to a new window. Felt like I'd cleared my desk and yet kept those tabs available for later.